# Using method as class method without declaring as class method

Tags: python, methods

I've subclassed a class that defines a method `format` and I want to override that method a bit:

```
class MyClass(SomeClass):

    def format(self, foo):
        # do some conditionals on foo
        r = SomeClass.format(self, foo)
        return r
```

In the superclass, `format` is defined as an instance method just as it is in the subclass.

Why does CPython allow this? Why define a method as an `@classmethod` instead?

Comment: `A().foo()` is just a syntactic sugar for `A.foo(A())`. This has nothing to do with subclasses.

Comment: I don't see where you are using a method as a class method. You have a `self` parameter.

Comment: @JohnColeman The `SomeClass.format` call is in the syntax I've known as a class method.

Comment: @DeepSpace Oh, I didn't know that, can I read on that more somewhere in the docs?

Comment: But the presence of the `self` parameter means that you are using a method bound to an instance. Compare: `s = 'test'` and then `str.upper(s)` is equivalent to `s.upper()`.

Comment: @JohnColeman Yes I see what the `self` indicates, but `SomeClass.format` is not bound to the instance `self` representing an instance of `MyClass`. That method is bound to the class `SomeClass`, of which `MyClass` is a subclass. How you've just described it, I would view as `MyClass().format(some_foo)`. The `self` parameter is filled by the object `MyClass()`, but in the example I am passing a different instance than what the calling object is represented by; i.e. `SomeClass().format(MyClass(), some_foo)` would fail but `SomeClass.format(MyClass(), some_foo)` doesnt.

Comment: @JohnColeman I was just surprised to see that I can use a method which is bound to the superclass, and call it on the superclass even though its an instance method, and pass a different instance to it.

Comment: @JohnColeman The long and skinny is I thought you could only call instance methods on instances since `self` is passed implicitly and in this case I was calling an instance method on the class and passing a specific instance.

Comment: @DeepSpace is that the descriptor protocol?

Comment: @DeepSpace Curious if I was correct regarding your syntax sugar notation, whether or not that is what the descriptor protocol does?